# Showing error - ' TypeError: Cannot read property 'comments' of null '

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why render comments function is not rendering my comment, What does this error mean?
this component is imported to a menu component which is further imported to app.js.
There's a shared dishes.js file which is imported in menu component, I have been able to render dishes but unable to render comments, why?

Here's my code below -

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Card, CardBody, CardImg, CardTitle, CardText} from 'reactstrap';

    class DishDetail extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
         super(props);

    }

     renderDish(dish){
         if(dish != null){
            return (
                <Card>
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.category} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            )
        }
       
         else {
             return (
                 <div></div>
             )
         }
    }

    renderComments(comments){
        if(comments == null){
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
        }

        const cmnt = comments.map((cmt) => {
            return(
                <li key={cmt.id}>
                    <p>{cmt.comment}</p>
                </li>
            )
        });

        return(
            <div className='col-12 col-md-5 m-1'>
              <h4> Comments </h4>
              <ul className='list-unstyled'>
                {cmnt}
              </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render(){

        const dish = this.props.dish;

        const renderComment = this.renderComments(dish.comments);

        return(
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1'">
                    {this.renderDish(dish)}
                  </div>
                   {renderComment}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

export default DishDetail;
```

Comment: Looks like your `this.props.dish` is `null`

Comment: can you share how the value in `this.props.dish` looks like ? . Does it contain a key `comments` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
const dish = this.props.dish;
const renderComment = this.renderComments(dish.comments);
```

That means `this.props.dish` is `null` in certain cases. Did you forget to give it an initial value?

Comment: It's initial value is null.

Comment: Since `dish` is null, you are essentially trying to access `null.comments`, which is obviously not going to work. If it is in a "proper" programming language, it will throw a `NullPointerException`. This should explain why you need to add an extra condition to check whether `dish` is `null`. As for optional chaining, i.e. `?.`, do not abuse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the props

```
const { dish } = this.props;
```

You can use optional chaining ([Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)) to make sure you return undefined if a property is not present in your object instead of returning an error .

```
const renderComment = this.renderComments(dish?.comments);
```

Now you can assign a default argument to your renderComments when the comments is undefined

```
renderComments(comments = null){
        ....
    }
```

Comment: It's also working when I put this condition after  const dish = this.props.dish and that is         const dish = this.props.dish

        console.log(dish);
        
        if (dish == null) {
            return (<div></div>);
        }     But why do we have to put condition in the render, although we assign the condition in renderDish() function?